# Does the arbitrary polynomials of the N-dimensional irreducible representation of SU(2) generate U(N)?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, hermitian-matrices

Assuming I have the $N$-dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ (The $N$-dimensional spin matrices $Sx$,$Sy$ and $Sz$) and I can consruct arbitrary polynomials from them of the form:

$$\sum{c_{nmk}S_x^nS_y^mS_z^k}$$
(allowing for alternating orders as well)
Can I generate any arbitrary unitary matrix in $N$ dimensions? Meaning, does any arbitrary unitary can be written as
$$U=e^{i\sum{c_{nmk}S_x^nS_y^mS_z^k}}?$$
I think the question can be alternatively written as, can any arbitrary nxn hermitian matrix be written as that polynomial.

Is there any standart proof?

I apologize for using notations from physics in case they are unclear.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you are looking for here. Are $S_x,S_y,S_z$ intended as bases of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$? If so, taking some polynomial like that won't give you an element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and so I don't see how you could exponentiate that (even allowing for alternating orders as that is simply taking a tensor product rather than a symmetric tensor product). You can take tensor products of representations to build new representations but not tensor products of the Lie algebra itself.

Comment: It will not be element of SU(2), but this is not my intention.

Also I am not talking about tensor product, but matrix multiplication, I just wonder wether any arbitrary hermitian (NxN) matrix can be written as a polynomial of the Sx,Sy,Sz basically.

Comment: Multiplying two Hermitian matrices will not give you a Hermitian matrix in general though (note: in maths we think of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ as the anti-Hermitian matrices but the problem still applies). In general, you cannot really talk about multiplying two elements of a Lie algebra. Even if you are imagining them inside some set of matrices, by picking a representation, this choice of representation greatly changes the answers.

Comment: In low dimension it is possible that matrix products of $S_x,S_y,S_z$ generate the whole set of matrices in that dimension so that will include the Hermitian ones but I doubt this holds in higher dimensions. Either way it would not be easy to guarantee that a particular product was Hermitian.

Comment: I understand, thanks (cool to know these differences, thank you!). But I somehow still want to get an answer for the question, I can then talk only about the “hermitian polynomials”, stuff like $S_xS_y+S_yS_x$, there I can make this claim? I have numerical and physical motivations to believe that this statement is true, this is why I’m asking. I would also like to know how I should focus my search in order to funds clue in the literature

Comment: Polynomials of generators will be in the huge [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra), which I assume, without proof, cannot fail to cover GL(N), where you may embed your *U* by restriction. Have you experimented with low *N* s?

Comment: I also assumed that $GL(N)$ can be spanned, however I fail to understand how such proofs looks like. I have read in an old paper something of the like “it’s a well known fact that $S_x,S_y,S_z$ and their multiplications can create $N^2$ linearly independent matrices.” The fact will enable me to have enough degrees of freedom to create the matrices I’m interested in, however while being completely logical I don’t understand how to prove this “well known” fact.